How to lose focus on ui:inputDate tag when the date selected is cleared or erased by the user using javascript?
My issue is on Mobile part. I have the Birthday date field on my Register Aura component and its using ui:inputDate tag. The client wants to redisplay the placeholder immediately when the date field is empty due to reset/clearing of selected date. Now, I already have a function that can add a placeholder as soon as the date field loses its focus. So I just wanna detect if the date field is empty so I can lose its focus or redirect the focus to my other elements in order to redisplay the Birthday placeholder. I tried using event listeners but its not really working. So far my handleBirthdayChange on my controller file looked like this below. Please disregard the other codes because its for other functionality:
handleBirthdayChange : function(component, event, helper) {

        var brand = component.get("v.brandParam");
        var currentDate = new Date();
        var dateThirteenYearsAgo = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear() - 14, currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getDate());
        var birthdayInput = component.find("birthday2");

        var birthday = new Date(birthdayInput.get("v.value"));
        if (birthday > dateThirteenYearsAgo){
            component.set("v.birthdayErrorMessage", brand == 'garage' ? $A.get("$Label.c.GRG_AgeRangeOverflowMessage"): $A.get("$Label.c.DYN_AgeRangeOverflowMessage"));
            component.set("v.showBirthdayError",true);
        } else {
            component.set("v.showBirthdayError",false);
        }

        // If there's already a date selected, this will remove both english and french css class for birthday placeholder.
        if (birthday != 'Invalid Date') {
            $A.util.addClass(birthdayInput, 'date-selected');
            $A.util.removeClass(birthdayInput, 'en-birthday-placeholder');
            $A.util.removeClass(birthdayInput, 'fr-birthday-placeholder');
        } else {
            $A.util.removeClass(birthdayInput, 'date-selected');
            // Add the appropriate class based on the language
            var placeholderClass = helper.getClassByLanguage(component);
            $A.util.addClass(birthdayInput, placeholderClass);

            // Remove the opposite language class
            helper.removeClassForOppositeLanguage(component);
        }

        var birthdayValue = birthdayInput.get("v.value");

        console.log('BirthdayValue: ', birthdayValue);
        // Check if the birthday value is empty or invalid
        if (!birthdayValue || isNaN(new Date(birthdayValue))) {
            // If the birthday value is empty or invalid, remove focus from the date field
            var submitButton = component.find("sfdc_confirm_button_container");
            submitButton.getElement().focus();
        }
    }

Here's my birthday date on my cmp file:
<div id="sfdc_birthday_container" class="sfdc dateOption2">
                                    <ui:inputDate aura:id="birthday2" labelClass="" value="{!v.birthdayValue}" blur="{!c.handleBirthdayChange}" displayDatePicker="true" format="{!v.dateFormat}" select="{!c.nullify}" keyup="{!c.nullify}" keypress="{!c.nullify}" updateOn="keypress, keyup" class="input sfdc_usernameinput sfdc" />
                                    <img src="{!$Resource.BirthdayDatePickerIcon}" alt="Date Picker Icon" class="sfdc-datepicker-icon"/>
                                </div>

I tried using event listeners and MutationObserver function but all of them aren't working at all.

To ensure that the placeholder is displayed whenever the birthday input field is empty on your Aura component, you can refine your approach by adding and refining event handlers specifically designed for this scenario. Based on your description, it seems that the focus needs to be programmatically managed to trigger the display of the placeholder when the input field is cleared.
Here's a step-by-step guide to refine your approach:
1. Improve Event Handling
First, ensure your event handling for ui:inputDate effectively checks for an empty field and then manages the focus appropriately. You seem to have the right idea in checking for the value of the input after interaction, but let's make it more robust:
Component Modification:
Change your ui:inputDate event handling from blur to change. The change event is better suited for detecting when the actual value of the input changes, which includes clearing the input.
<ui:inputDate aura:id="birthday2" value="{!v.birthdayValue}" change="{!c.handleBirthdayChange}" displayDatePicker="true" format="{!v.dateFormat}" class="input sfdc_usernameinput sfdc" />

2. Refine the Controller
Adjust your handleBirthdayChange function to explicitly handle the scenario where the date field is cleared:
handleBirthdayChange : function(component, event, helper) {
    var birthdayInput = component.find("birthday2");
    var birthdayValue = birthdayInput.get("v.value");
    
    if (!birthdayValue) {  // Checks if the birthday field is empty
        $A.util.removeClass(birthdayInput, 'date-selected');
        var placeholderClass = helper.getClassByLanguage(component);
        $A.util.addClass(birthdayInput, placeholderClass);
        
        // Force focus change to re-trigger placeholder display
        var otherElement = component.find("otherElementId"); // Replace with actual other element's aura:id
        if (otherElement) {
            otherElement.getElement().focus();
            birthdayInput.getElement().blur();  // Optionally, force blur if necessary
        }
    } else {
        var currentDate = new Date();
        var dateThirteenYearsAgo = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear() - 14, currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getDate());
        var birthday = new Date(birthdayValue);
        
        if (birthday > dateThirteenYearsAgo){
            var brand = component.get("v.brandParam");
            component.set("v.birthdayErrorMessage", brand == 'garage' ? $A.get("$Label.c.GRG_AgeRangeOverflowMessage"): $A.get("$Label.c.DYN_AgeRangeOverflowMessage"));
            component.set("v.showBirthdayError", true);
        } else {
            component.set("v.showBirthdayError", false);
        }

        // Managing the class for showing that the date is selected
        $A.util.addClass(birthdayInput, 'date-selected');
        helper.removeClassForOppositeLanguage(component);
    }
}

3. Handle Focus Appropriately
If focusing another element to trigger the placeholder doesn't work or seems too forceful, consider directly manipulating the placeholder's visibility through CSS or additional JavaScript handling. You can also adjust the aura:id of another focusable element to force a shift in focus briefly and then return it if needed.
Additional Considerations:

Make sure your JavaScript helper functions (getClassByLanguage and removeClassForOppositeLanguage) handle class assignments correctly based on the language.
Double-check that all necessary resources (like icons) and styles are properly linked and applied.
Ensure that any client-side validations do not interfere with the focus manipulation.

This approach should help you manage the placeholder visibility more effectively based on the input field's value.

I tried implementing this but the placeholder is still nor reappearing after I click reset/clear on date picker.

thank you so much for making this comment. I really appreciate it.
